# How to retrive current millisecond from TIME_OF_DAY_INFO Structure

Tags: c++, objective-c++

The following does not give the current milli second from the server
tod_msecs
Type: DWORD

The number of milliseconds from an arbitrary starting point (system reset).

Typically, this member is read twice, once when the process begins and again at the end. To determine the elapsed time between the process's start and finish, you can subtract the first value from the second

Comment: It's not clear, how you call the method, what it gives you and what you expect.

Comment: NET_API_STATUS Status = NetRemoteTOD(Server, (LPBYTE *)&TimeOfDay); GetLocalTime(&LocalSystemTime)..This is the method.....I need to get the time from the server in format say 11:53:04:456 in which 456 represents micro secons

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to call GetTickCount function while starting the process and GetTickCount while ending the process and find the difference. if you run the process for more than 49.7 days then use GetTickCount64 instead

If you want more accurate implementation then go for QueryPerformanceCounter() and QueryPerformanceFrequency(). refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644900(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I use the following code to compare the system time and the server time.GetTickCount function gives the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started.But i need the exact millisecond value ranging from 0 to 999.  Code follows :              NET_API_STATUS Status = NetRemoteTOD(Server, (LPBYTE *)&TimeOfDay);
GetLocalTime(&LocalSystemTime);  -> from this i get hours ,seconds,and miliseconds .I also need the same format from the server.Only the milliseconds from the server could not be retrived

Comment: @Techy when you call GetTickCount twice and subtract the first value from the second you will get the exact duration of your process. Coming to your code, did you try retrieving tod_msecs which will give the milli seconds so you need to obtain it twice and subtract it. GetLocalTime just give you your system time, it is not the elapsed time

Comment: i retrived the values of  tod_msecs and subtracted.But it gave a very large value which is not at all relative.

Comment: TO make it simple i need to get the time from server in format 11:50:05:365

Comment: @Techy, is your objective is to find the number of milliseconds ellapsed or the current time? If you get a big value in milliseconds try to divide it by 1000 to obtain seconds and then by 60 to obtain minutes then by 12 to obtain hours and format it to what you want